# How can I convert a JavaScript object to an array

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following javascript object, in an array. I am using PHP's json_encode to get this value

```
[ { January=100},  { February=100} ]
```

I am trying to convert the following objects to

```
["January",100],["February",100]
```

I have searched around a lot and couldn't find an answer.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to do this in JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: You should try to convert object and its fields to arrays and then serialize result.

Comment: No you don't. The code you're showing is not JSON, and certainly not something that will come rolling out of `json_encode`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to do this in Javascript, it can be done very easily using a library like Lodash:

```
server_array.map(_.toPairs)
```

Using native Javascript `map` function, with lodash's [toPairs](https://lodash.com/docs#toPairs)

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the incorrect syntax of your example javascript object code...

This is how to convert a javascript object to an array:

```
var newArray = []
for (var i in yourObject)
    if(yourObject.hasOwnProperty(i))
        newArray.push([i,yourObject[i]])
```

The above will yield the results your looking for.